# Yii2 datetimepicker запретить выбор прошедших часов

Tags: yii2, datetimepicker

Всем добрый день!
Работаю в yii2 с виджетом datetimepicker. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы нельзя было выбирать прошедшую дату и время. Что касается прошедшей даты, это достигается такими настройками:

```
'minDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
```

Но вот что бы я не делал, для времени сделать это не удается. Допустим, сейчас 21 час, тогда мне хотелось бы чтобы за сегодняшнюю дату нельзя было выбрать время раньше 21 часа. Но пока что я вижу только такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. можно выбрать все равно любой час. Как запретить такой выбор?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
'minDate' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
```

Т.е.  у Вас время заполняется по умолчанию нулями и можно выбрать любой час за текущие сутки.
Правда формат времени в самом плагине, на всякий случай, уточните.